# How can I center align a label of a node in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, labels

How can I make the label `{stable \\ equilibrium}` in the below code, so that there is a line break, and with the text center aligned?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0, width=\textwidth]
    \addplot [domain=0:1] {30 + 70*x};
    \addplot [domain=0:1] {40 + 20*x};
    \node [label={[label distance=2em]80: {stable equilibrium}}] at (0, 40) {};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\node [label={[align=center,text width=2cm,label distance=2em]80: {stable\\ equilibrium}}] at (0, 40) {};` but why do you write all the text in the label (and not in the `{}` brackets)?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to put it in the `{}` brackets when I am specifying the angle that the label lies at. I learnt this code through copy-pasting.

Comment: E.g. `    \node [yshift=2em,anchor=south west,align=center,text width=2cm] at (0, 40){stable\\ equilibrium};` or load the positioning library for better node positioning. (And lipsum is not needed for your MWE... ;-)

Comment: @ahorn, any news? you receive two answers ...

Comment: @Zarko the first comment by marmot was what I was looking for. The label was intended to be for the intercept with the vertical axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the node consists only of the text, it might be easier to put the text into the `{}` brackets. This makes it a bit easier to deal with the node/text, e.g. when you decide to connect it to a point with an arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0, width=\textwidth]
    \addplot [domain=0:1] {30 + 70*x};
    \addplot [domain=0:1] {40 + 20*x};
    \node [yshift=2.7em,anchor=south west,align=center,text width=2cm] at (0, 40){stable\\ equilibrium};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you will liked:

[image]

used is `tikz` library `intersections`, also is redefined `pin` nodes option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every pin/.append style = {pin edge={<-, shorten <=2pt, semithick}, align=center},
                       ]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        width=\linewidth,
        domain=0:1]
    \addplot [name path=A] {30 + 70*x};
    \addplot [name path=B] {40 + 20*x};
    \path [name intersections ={%
           of=A and B, by={[pin=300:stable\\ equilibrium]}
                                }];
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```